# Alternate URL router for Django

Tags: django, url-routing

How would you go about using django models and templates, but not the URL routing system?  I'd like to swap out the `urls.py` system for something like PHP where the URL tells you exactly where the code is that's running.  Or maybe something more automagic like rails uses -- where the URL always includes the same components like app name, model name and view name.

I just disagree with the line from the [django philosophy statement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#id8) that "Tying URLs to Python function names is a Bad And Ugly Thing."  Pretty URLs just aren't all that important to me, and IMVHO not worth the complexity of climbing through a maze of indirection in multiple `urls.py` files and dozens of regexes to find out what code runs behind a particular URL.  It's a personal choice, right?  Django is generally pretty modular allowing you to swap out the major components for other ones.  So, how would I swap out the part which takes the request URL and decides which view to run?

Are there any alternate URL routers for django out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is one line in your urls.py that matches everything, and then just write your handler/dispatcher as a view. That handler does whatever you want based on the parts of the URL....

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of anyone successfully swapping out Django's URL routing system. There's certainly no hook for it - `core.handlers.base.BaseHandler.get_response` calls `urlresolvers.RegexURLResolver` directly. Conceivably, you could add a middleware at the bottom of the stack that dispatches to your own URL resolution system and returns the response, thus bypassing the Django system, but it's a bit kludgy.

If you're after something more like Rails, you might want to try one of the other frameworks - [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid.html), for example, uses a system of Routes very similar to Rails'. Pyramid is much more pluggable than Django, so you should be able to plug in the Jinja2 templating system, which is based on Django's. However, there's no way to use Django's ORM seperately, so you'd need to use SQLAlchemy (which can be used in a way that's not massively different).